# Is there some name for a matrix which is unitarily similar to its negative?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have a code spitting out matrices $A$. I am trying to understand the structure of these matrices.

I have identified that we can always unitarily transform the matrix $A$ to $-A$ via a transform $A'=U^\dagger A U=-A$.

Is there any special name for this type of matrix?

And does this propery imply any others?

Comment: It implies $\operatorname{tr}A=0$. On a vector space of odd dimension, it implies $\det A=0$.

Comment: It also implies that $tr(A)=0$ (more generally that for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ appearing with a Jordan block of length $n$ you get that $-\lambda$ appears with Jordan block of length $n$ as well).